# Amanda backup software using postfix generates invalid sendmail command line option '-s'

Tags: postfix, sendmail, amanda

I recently updated postfix on my CentOS 6 server to support a new email relay, and everything is working except my Amanda backup software, which is no longer sending status emails. When I run "amreport" on the command line, it gives me these errors:

```
sendmail: invalid option -- 's'
sendmail: invalid option -- 's'
sendmail: fatal: usage: sendmail [options]
amreport: mail command exited with status 75
```

However, in my amanda.conf file, I have this:

```
mailer "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t"
```

Where is Amanda and/or postfix getting the "s" option? Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance to all who respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS 6 is of-course [complete legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#End-of-support_schedule) and has been for years.

---

Amanda uses, or rather attempts to use the `-s`  switch to set the `Subject:` line of the e-mail message it generates.

See [`man amanda.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/amanda.conf)

> **`mailer string`**
> Default found by configure. A mail program that can send mail with `'MAILER -s "subject" user < message_file'`.

That  `-s` switch is AFAIK  not supported in either the [canonical `sendmail`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sendmail.sendmail) command nor the [Postfix compatibility sendmail](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sendmail.postfix) command.

Rather than using the `sendmail` command, use the [`mail`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mail) command or the slightly more advanced [`mailx`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mailx)  command instead.

Comment: Replacing "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t" with "/bin/mailx" fixed the problem.  Thanks.